# Autofocus text field on mobile, but no keyboard?

Tags: html, mobile, autofocus

As part of my login and registration forms, if there are errors then it will autofocus the related field. Actually, it not as simple as I thought. Let me try to explain!

Basically, on this project, pages are loaded with AJAX. Forms may include an `autofocus` attribute. This works great, but on mobile it just shows the cursor without bringing up the keyboard, meaning you still have to tap the input to start typing.

Am I missing something, or do I have to double-up the focussing with something like

```
document.querySelector("[autofocus]").focus();
// with appropriate verification that the element exists, of coursr
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In mobile devices (at least in Apple's Safari), the keyboard isn't allowed to show up without the user clicking on the input field. It's by design, and I don't think there is much you can do about it.
http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-Javascript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: I don't think this is 100% true, I have a site with a dropdown menu containing an input, and when the dropdown is opened it calls `.focus()` on the input.  When I open the dropdown in Safari on my iPad 2 it brings up the keyboard automatically, before I click on the input.

Comment: It's not clear, but the quora link does hint that the problem is that automatic events (such as onload, ready, etc) all fail to display the keyboard on focus() - anything that's triggered from a user event though, like onclick etc, if they then call focus() it does show the keyboard.

Comment: It's not that the user has to click on the actual input for it work, it's that the user has to *interact* with the page, which I suspect means generating any event